# Sorting a Multidimensional Arrays PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array as

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
      (
          [attribute_pa_weight] => 500g-pack
      )
  [1] => Array
     (
        [attribute_pa_weight] => 1kg-pack
     )

 )
```

Would need the Output to be

```
   Array
  (
       [attribute_pa_weight] => Array
    (
        [0] => 500g-pack
        [1] => 1kg-pack
    )
  )
```

Want the sorting without mentioning the key value to sort because we have the dey coming dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP function [array_reduce](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) can be used here:

```
<?php
$a = [['attribute_pa_weight'=>'500g-pack'],['attribute_pa_weight'=>'1kg-pack']];

$res = array_reduce(
    $a, // source array
    function($acc, $el) {
        if (!isset($acc[key($el)])) $acc[key($el)] = [];
        array_push($acc[key($el)], $el[key($el)]);
        return $acc;
    },
    [] // initial result
);
    
print_r($res);
```

You can try code at [PHPize.online](https://phpize.online/?phpses=220f4e1202021f8ac62b7b163d957119&sqlses=null&php_version=php7&sql_version=mysql80)

Answer (score 1):

Another candidate for this job would be [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)!

```php
$input = [
    ['attribute_pa_weight' => '500g-pack'],
    ['attribute_pa_weight' => '1kg-pack'],
];

$output['attribute_pa_weight'] = array_map(fn ($v) => $v['attribute_pa_weight'], $input);

print_r($output);
```

If you can't or don't want to use [arrow functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arrow.php) (need PHP `^7.4.0`).

```php
$output['attribute_pa_weight'] = array_map(function ($value) {
    return $value['attribute_pa_weight'];
}, $input);

print_r($output);
```

And if you want it dynamic, you could create a function.

```php
$merge = function ($name) use ($input) {
    return [$name => array_map(fn ($v) => $v[$name], $input)];
};

print_r($merge('attribute_pa_weight'));
```

Comment: OP doesn't mention what sorting is required. You might want to show how to sort the final output. Great job.